# Difference between dp and sp (The other definitions that I have seen was still confusing me)?

Tags: android-studio

I am currently doing some research on dpi and sp. What is the main difference between density-independent pixels (dp) and scale-independent pixels?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "px", "dip", "dp" and "sp"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp)

Comment: So technically to put into one's own words, dp is based on screen density (screen density is how many px appear within a fixed area of the screen) and sp is based on the user's configuration (font size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 **DP** (density-independent pixels) is 1 pixel on a 160 dpi screen.

**SP** (Scale-independent Pixels) - this resembles the dp unit, however it is likewise scaled by the user's text dimension setting.